# Using case_when() inside a function to refer to column names that is passed to the function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to use case_when() inside a function. The idea for the function is to take a specified column, search it for a particular term, and then return true if the term is in that column, and false if it is not.

However, I am struggling with trying to make case_when refer to a column that is passed in at the level of the function - at least, the way I have succeeded doing it seems a bit hacky, in that I pass in a character string and then convert it to a symbol, and then pass it to case_when. Is there a way of referring to a column more dynamically directly in case_when?:

```
test_tibble <- tibble(col_a = c("Here I am", "Nope", "Nothing", "I am here"))

test_function <- function(target_item,
                          data = test_tibble,
                          variable_name,
                          prefix = "check_") {
  
  variable_name <- as.symbol(variable_name)
  
  data <- 
    data %>% 
    mutate("{prefix}{target_item}" := case_when(grepl(target_item, {{variable_name}}) ~ TRUE,
                                                TRUE ~ FALSE))
  
  return(data)

}

test_function("ere", variable_name = "col_a")
```

In the real use case, I might need to refer to many different named columns, so it is important that I can specify the column name at the top of the function.

Comment: Do you want to pass in the name of the column as a string or as a symbol?

Comment: Either way is fine but I would rather not have to write e.g., 'as.symbol(my_column)' when passing it in. When I've tried just writing the column name but not as a string things seemed to go wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing specific about `case_when` when it comes to passing in column names to a function. It all depends on how you want to pass in the column name. In fact it's not really clear why you are using `case_when` at all. You can just use `grepl` directory since it will return a TRUE/FALSE value already.

If you want to pass in a string, use

```
test_function <- function(target_item,
                          data = test_tibble,
                          variable_name,
                          prefix = "check_") {

  data <- 
    data %>% 
    mutate("{prefix}{target_item}" := case_when(grepl(target_item, .data[[variable_name]]) ~ TRUE,
                                                TRUE ~ FALSE))
  
  return(data)
  
}

test_function("ere", variable_name = "col_a")
```

If you want to pass in a symbol, use

```
test_function <- function(target_item,
                          data = test_tibble,
                          variable_name,
                          prefix = "check_") {

  data <- 
    data %>% 
    mutate("{prefix}{target_item}" := case_when(grepl(target_item, {{variable_name}}) ~ TRUE,
                                                TRUE ~ FALSE))
  
  return(data)
  
}

test_function("ere", variable_name = col_a)
```

Comment: Thanks - I did not know the .data solution!

Answer (score 1):

you may also use `get` function and remove the `{{ }}` and `as.symbol`

```r
test_tibble <- tibble(col_a = c("Here I am", "Nope", "Nothing", "I am here"))
#> Error in tibble(col_a = c("Here I am", "Nope", "Nothing", "I am here")): could not find function "tibble"

test_function <- function(target_item,
                          data = test_tibble,
                          variable_name,
                          prefix = "check_") {
  

  data <- 
    data %>% 
    mutate("{prefix}{target_item}" := case_when(grepl(target_item, get(variable_name)) ~ TRUE,
                                                TRUE ~ FALSE))
  
  return(data)
  
}


test_function("ere", variable_name = "col_a")
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, this is also a great alternative